# Upgrade Wordpress CiviCRM Version from 4.5.2 to 4.6.5

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I have a good installation of CiviCRM on Wordpress, but now i want to upgrade to version 4.6.5 and when ik upgrade, the upgrade stops at 4.6.alpha7

I am trying for 4 hours to get an solution So i have tried to export the structure and data end make a new database  with the original structure imports. But nothing will work..

**EDIT:**
I have checked all the tables with a compare program,
Left= Current version 4.5.2 / working civicrm (Backup / before Upgrade)
Right= Original civicrm.mysql version 4.5.2

**RESULT:**
Only tables civicrm_value_**** are not in the right (original) version.

**EDIT 2:**
I can upgrade to version 4.5.8 without problems. If i want to upgrade then to 4.6.6 It will also stop at 4.6.alpha7 (error below)

I have also checked if there is a table civicrm_mailing_abtest but this table does not exist.

I hope someone can help me to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot. It is a fantastic plugin!! ( CiviCRM )

With kind regards,

Mark

This is the error:

```
[Error: Upgrade DB to 4.6.alpha7]
Fout Veld   fout waarde
Type    DB_Error
Code    -1
Message DB Error: unknown error
Mode    16
UserInfo    ALTER TABLE civicrm_mailing_abtest ADD COLUMN `created_id` int unsigned COMMENT 'FK to Contact ID', ADD COLUMN `created_date` datetime COMMENT 'When was this item created', ADD COLUMN `testing_criteria` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, ADD COLUMN `winner_criteria` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, ADD CONSTRAINT FK_civicrm_mailing_abtest_created_id FOREIGN KEY (`created_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact`(`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL [nativecode=1215 ** Cannot add foreign key constraint]
DebugInfo   ALTER TABLE civicrm_mailing_abtest ADD COLUMN `created_id` int unsigned COMMENT 'FK to Contact ID', ADD COLUMN `created_date` datetime COMMENT 'When was this item created', ADD COLUMN `testing_criteria` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, ADD COLUMN `winner_criteria` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, ADD CONSTRAINT FK_civicrm_mailing_abtest_created_id FOREIGN KEY (`created_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact`(`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL [nativecode=1215 ** Cannot add foreign key constraint]
PEAR_Exception: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown
- DB_Error: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown
Exception trace
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue upgrading from 4.5.8 to 4.6.4, what worked for me was to manually remove the civicrm_mailing_abtest table from the database. 
Restore your database backup before the upgrade and login to mysql

**Update:**
To restore your backup database:

```
mysql -u root -p // login to mysql

drop database civicrm; // delete the current database, the one is failing to upgrade

create database civicrm; // create a new empty database

quit // logout from mysql
```

**Restoring the database backup**

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost civicrm < /path/to/your/database/backup/civicrm-database-backup.sql // write the backup to the new empty database
```

Replace "/path/to/your/database/backup" with your backup directory and "civicrm-database-backup.sql" with the name of your Civicrm backup SQL file.

**Check for the existing civicrm_mailing_abtest table**

```
mysql -u root -p

use civicrm; // replace civicrm with the name of your database

show tables; // it will give you a list with the civicrm database tables
```

If the civicrm_mailing_abtest is listed in the output, remove it, as it shouldn't be there, the A/B Test mailing was introduced in CiviCRM 4.6

```
drop table civicrm_mailing_abtest; // this will remove the table
```

After that proceed with the upgrade again.

Hope this helps

**Update 2:**
If you have permission errors after the restore, you will need to grant permission to the civicrm mysql user

```
mysql -u root -p

grant all on civicrm.* to 'username' identified by 'password';

flush privileges;
```

Comment: This answer should really include a `DROP DATABASE civicrm` and `CREATE DATABASE civicrm` before restoring the database backup.  Restoring a database backup only overwrites tables that existed in the backup; newly-created tables are NOT written over.  That's what leads to this problem in the first place!

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated the answer with restore instructions

Comment: Run this in mysql: SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G, there should be an Foreign Key errors section in the output. Paste the result here.